# Using Scanner and Patterns always throws exception

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to read an input String - if it conforms to a predefined pattern, it should be returned. If the input is not correct, an exception should be thrown.

Here's what I have so far. My problem is that regardless of input it always throws an exception. What could I be doing wrong here?

```java
public String readPostCode() throws InputMismatchException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String postcode;
    System.out.println("Please enter a Postcode");
    postcode = in.next(this.pattern);
    return postcode;
}
```

When I use the above method in a try/catch statement, an InputMismatchException is always caught.

EDIT: Here's the definition of pattern:

```java
public Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(   "[a-zA-Z]" +
                                            "([0-9]|[a-zA-Z])" +
                                            "(|[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])" +
                                            " [0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]");
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception and what is `this.pattern` ?

Comment: Have you specified this.pattern as a corresponding regex? (e.g. [A-Z0-9]{3}+?) If the regex is undefined, this may be throwing the InputMismatchException. From the looks of it, you're trying to check for syntactic validity as you're inputting the postcode. Try inputting the postal code, then checking for syntactic validity after the fact.

If the Regex doesn't match, discard the input. 
Otherwise, keep it.

Comment: @RobEarl the only line that could throw an `InputMismatchException` is `postcode = ...`.

Comment: @JanDvorak, yep, I realised that after posting but didn't delete as we still need to know what `this.pattern` is.

Comment: @RobEarl you can always edit a comment until five minuts after posting it.

Comment: I've added the definition of this.pattern. So basically it's better for me to just read a String, then check it? Still don't get why it throws exceptions even when the String matches the pattern!

Comment: Also, where are you getting the input from?

Comment: @TylerJFisher Scanner(System.in)

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: code untested.

For a Canadian postal code (since locale was not defined)

Using: (^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]\s?[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]$)

> Example of accepted input: A2B 3P7

```
public String readPostCode(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String postcode = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        try {
           if(postcode.matches("^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]\s?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"){
              return postcode;
            }
         } catch (InputMismatchException IME){
              System.out.println("Input does not match required format");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` delimits on whitespace by default. To read input containing spaces, set it to delimit on newlines only:

```
in.useDelimiter("\n");
```

You could also simplify the pattern quite a bit. Make it case insensitive and use `{n,m}` to specify a pattern which repeats at least `n` and at most `m` times:

```
Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,3}\\s?[0-9][A-Z]{2}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

**Note** this is for a British postcode, e.g. `LS1 2AA`.